# Node-ACl throws uhandled rejection error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, acl

i am using ACL module in my express application.At the start of the server i define some roles and their permissions using the acl.allow() function.

But it logs in a error saying undefined rejection type.The error vanishes on giving a callback with error param.But i am not very sure about what is throwing the error and how it should be handled.

My snippet code which i am using is :

```
    var aclmodule = new acl(new acl.mongodbBackend(config.db.URL, "accesscontrol_"));
    aclmodule.allow([
    {
        roles:['rolea'],
        allows:[
            {resources:['a','b'], permissions:['*']}
        ]
    },
    {
        roles:['roleb','rolec'],
        allows:[
            {resources:['a'], permissions:['view']}
        ]
    },
    {
        roles:['rolec'],
        allows:[
            {resources:['o'], permissions:['view','edit']}
        ]
    }
]);

});
```

The error logged in console is :

> Unhandled rejection TypeError: undefined is not a function
>       at D:\user\web\myapp-web\node_modules\acl\lib\mongodb-backend.js:119:15
>
> ```
> at D:\myapp\web\myapp-web\node_modules\acl\node_modules\async\lib\async.
> ```
>
> js:607:21
>       at D:\myapp\web\myapp-web\node_modules\acl\node_modules\async\lib\async.
>   js:246:17
>       at iterate (D:\myapp\web\myapp-web\node_modules\acl\node_modules\async\l
>   ib\async.js:146:13)
>       at async.eachSeries (D:\myapp\web\myapp-web\node_modules\acl\node_module
>   s\async\lib\async.js:162:9)
>       at _asyncMap (D:\myapp\web\myapp-web\node_modules\acl\node_modules\async
>   \lib\async.js:245:13)
>       at Object.mapSeries (D:\myapp\web\myapp-web\node_modules\acl\node_module
>   s\async\lib\async.js:228:23)
>       at Object.async.series (D:\myapp\web\myapp-web\node_modules\acl\node_mod
>   ules\async\lib\async.js:605:19)
>       at Object.MongoDBBackend.end (D:\myapp\web\myapp-web\node_modules\acl\li
>   b\mongodb-backend.js:35:11)
>       at Object.tryCatcher (D:\myapp\web\myapp-web\node_modules\acl\node_modul
>   es\bluebird\js\main\util.js:26:23)
>       at Object.ret [as endAsync] (eval at  (D:\myapp\web\myapp-web
>   \node_modules\acl\node_modules\bluebird\js\main\promisify.js:163:12),

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is `config.db.URL` a string? If so, this is the cause of your errors. The line it is failing on is (in `mongodb-backend.js`):

`self.db.collection(...` -- it is saying that `.collection()` is undefined. (Which would make sense if "self.db" were only a string.)

Node-acl expects a **database instance** when creating a new `mongodbBackend`, like it [says in the docs](https://github.com/OptimalBits/node_acl#documentation) -- for [example](https://github.com/OptimalBits/node_acl/issues/41):

```
 mongoose.connection.on('connected', function() {
    var myAcl = new acl(new acl.mongodbBackend(mongoose.connection.db));
});
```